# footmisc and chappg incompatibility

Tags: footmisc

I have a document in which I have to use `footmisc` with the option `perpage` to manage footnotes and also it is needed to reset the page enumeration by chapter for which I tried `chappg` package. But the combination of those two makes that chapters start at page zero.
This is my MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{chappg}
\usepackage[perpage,symbol]{footmisc}
\textheight=8cm
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
Text\footnote{abc}
\end{document}
```

And a picture of the undesired page numbering

[image]

I have compiled the MWE with TeXLive 2022

There is a way to avoid this issue?

Comment: you can try to load chappg after footmisc.

Comment: I can confirm that Ulrike's suggestion works.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Loading `chappf` after `footmisc` makes everything works as expected. After a quick look at the corresponding manuals, I didn't find anything about the interaction between these two packages. Then, it may be helpful for others to have an answer here. You could write your comment as an answer @UlrikeFischer